# Is it possible to get a message from Google Sheets to show on a Flex message template(Line Bot)

Tags: line, dialogflow-es, webhooks, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am working on a LINE bot using Dialogflow, webhooks, and a Google Sheet database. I have a Flex message template, but some of the data in Flex message is blank. I need to get the data from the Google Sheet database to show in the Flex message that is blank. Is this possible?
How can I do it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AExhm.png)

I need to get the data from the Google Sheet database to show in the Flex message that is blank.By using web hook.